# Sequence and Rangify list of book indexes

Tags: c#, sorting, indexing

I'm coding a MS word based register tool for my office project where application will do complex SR based on Nummer (title numbers, Keywords and Law name) and create a register for each input word file.

Currently application is coded and 90% completed, for latest change request by client, I need following to be added to application.

currently I'm having list of title numbers like

> 1, 2, 3, 3.1, 3.2,3.3,3.4,4,5,6, 7.1.1,7.1.2,7.1.3

The requirement is to sort them in correct order ascending and `Rangify` the near numbers.

For example form the above :

> 1,2,3

should be rangify as:

> 1-3
>
> 3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4

should be rangify as:

> 3.1-3.4

and

> 4,5,6

as

> 4-5

and

> 7.1.1,7.1.2,7.1.3

as

> 7.1.1-7.1.3

Ultimately in above list, items should be sequenced and Rangify as bellow :

> 1-3, 3.1-3.4, 4-6, 7.1.1-7.1.3

I tried separating items by number of levels and adding them to sorted list and checking distance and make them in to one test range yet that didn't work our for me)

Then with some googling I found following c# function yet this function is for integers only

```
IEnumerable<string> Rangify(IList<int> input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; ) {
        var start = input[i];
        int size = 1;
        while (++i < input.Count && input[i] == start + size)
            size++;

        if (size == 1)
            yield return start.ToString();
        else if (size == 2) {
            yield return start.ToString();
            yield return (start + 1).ToString();
        } else if (size > 2)
            yield return start + " - " + (start + size - 1);
    }
}
```

So can someone please instruct me to get a solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: `1, 2, 3, 3.1-3.4, 4-6, 7.1.1-7.1.3` maybe 1-3, 3.1-3.4, 4-6, 7.1.1-7.1.3 ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct... I have edited and changed it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
    private static List<string> SortTitleNums(List<string> titleNums)
    {            
        // list that'll hold the result of current operation
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        // sorts the input array
        titleNums.Sort();

        // field that will indicate start and end of a sequence
        bool sequenceStarted = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < titleNums.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            // checks if the value is greater than current value by 1 to find sequence
            if (Convert.ToInt32(titleNums[i + 1].Replace(".", "")) - Convert.ToInt32(titleNums[i].Replace(".", "")) == 1)

                // if sequence is found we add this value to the result list and change sequnceStarted field to true.
              { if (!sequenceStarted) { result.Add(titleNums[i] + "-"); sequenceStarted = true; } }

            // if sequence is found and next value does not refer to the sequence than we append the record with current value and change 
            //value for sequenceStarted field to false. If sequence not found than we just add the number.
            else if (sequenceStarted) { result[result.Count - 1] += titleNums[i]; sequenceStarted = false; } else result.Add(titleNums[i]);                
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Example of usage :

```
    static void Main()
    {
        List<string> titleNums = new List<string>()
        {
            "1", "2", "6", "3", "3.1", "3.2", "3.3", "8", "7.1.1", "7.1.2", "8.1.1", "7.1.3", "7.2.1", 
        };

        titleNums = SortTitleNums(titleNums);

        foreach (var item in titleNums)
            Console.WriteLine(item);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Output : `"1-3", "3.1-3.3", "6", "7.1.1-7.1.3", "7.2.1", "8"`

Comment: @AshanChathurika Updated with comments. Hope it'll help you to understand the logic behind this code.

Comment: @AshanChathurika Glad that it helped :)